# vim plugin FuzzyFinderTextMate error

Tags: vim

I installed the vim plugin on many different ways. I try to start it with Ctrl-T but what I get is always that error:
E492: Not an editor command: FuzzyFinderTextMate

Comment: Please clarify "many different ways" - is the .vim file containing the plugin in a directory you know is having its contents sourced? From quick googling, it appears you also need a ruby gem - have you installed that appropriately as well?

Comment: That plugin should not map Ctrl+T as that is a tag navigation command. I've had version issues with that plugin in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was getting the same error "E492: Not an editor command: FuzzyFinderTextMate" with OS X 10.6.2.  It turns out the default vim installation in Snow Leopard was not compiled with ruby  support.  Once I recompiled vim with ruby support, the plugin worked as expected.

The installation steps that worked for me:

1. Compile Vim with Ruby using [macports](http://www.macports.org/): `sudo port install vim +ruby`
2. Download [fuzzyfinder.vim 2.16](http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=9643) to ~/.vim/plugin
3. Download [fuzzy_file_finder.rb](http://github.com/jamis/fuzzy_file_finder/raw/master/lib/fuzzy_file_finder.rb) to ~/.vim/ruby
4. Download [fuzzyfinder_textmate.vim](http://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate/raw/master/fuzzyfinder_textmate.vim) to ~/.vim/plugin
5. Added the following line to ~/.vimrc: `map <C-j> :FuzzyFinderTextMate<CR>`

If you run into problems, check the [original](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/10/10/coming-home-to-vim) and [update](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2009/1/28/the-future-of-fuzzyfinder-textmate) blog posts for help.

Comment: I do not think any version Of FuzzyFinder_Textmate is supported anymore. Karmen's answer of command-t is probably the correct answer now

Answer (score 2):

command-t is the way to go now in my opinion. Works awesomely!!

https://wincent.com/products/command-t

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this plugin has lost its original flair. Doesn't seem to work well. Read more: http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2009/1/28/the-future-of-fuzzyfinder-textmate and https://wincent.com/blog/fuzzyfinder

Comment: It works well, it just takes some effort to find the versions of every required file that work well together. Have a look at github for fuzzyfinder_textmate and fuzzy_file_finder.rb:

http://github.com/jamis/fuzzy_file_finder/network
http://github.com/jamis/fuzzyfinder_textmate

The most recent versions work well with FuzzyFinder 2.22.3.

Comment: http://github.com/jonuts/fuzzyfinder_textmate - that version works well and includes the correct version fo fuzzy finder. It may not be maintained anymore, but it still feels like the best option to me.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on 10.6.4:

Grab fuzzyfinder.vim and fuzzyfinder_textmate.vim from http://github.com/sethbc/fuzzyfinder_textmate.  Drop both of those into ~/.vim/plugin

Then grab fuzzy_file_finder.rb from github.com/jamis/fuzzy_file_finder and drop it into ~/.vim/ruby

In .vimrc, I added:

```
map <leader>t :FuzzyFinderTextMate<CR>
```

so "\t" (without the quotes) will launch, though you should map whatever feels best for you (see other answers/comments).

(My apologies for the dearth of links.  It seems I lack sufficient reputation to post more than one link.)